# angularjs: only set background-image on ngStyle if url is defined

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a property on the scope which can hold an url (bgUrl) of an image. Now I would like to use this image as a background image of a 'div'. However, if the property is undefined I would like to use a default image which is defined by the class bg-image. Now I can do it like

```
<img ng-show="bgUrl" ng-src="bgUrl"/>
<div ng-hide="bgUrl" class="bg-image"/>
```

However, I would like to combine this into one element. I tried something like this

```
<div class="gb-image" ng-style="{true: 'background-image': 'url(\'' + bgUrl + '\')'}[bgUrl]"/>
```

I just copied some code from google (no idea if this can ever work). One thing is clear though, this doesn't work :)
What would be a nice angular way to solve this and can my solution work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right way is a directive way:

```
app.directive('bg', function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if(scope.bgUrl){
            element.css("background-image","url("+scope.bgUrl+")");
          } else {
            element.addClass("bg-default");             
          }
        }
    }
});
```

Take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/xYEjpp?p=preview

Comment: nice, I guess you're right! Thats the one I will use. Just curious, is the thing I tried possible too (the solution with only one div) ?  And do you know how ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri honestly , i don't know how to use a syntax like in your example. as for me it is not readable and too much logic/code in a view..